# Возможно ли создание ОС, запускающую исполняемые файлы от Win, Mac, Linux

Tags: windows, ос, macos, linux

Возник спор, решил спросить у аудитории (:

В общем, чисто теоретически возможно ли создание ОС, у которой исполняемыми файлами будут являться .exe .deb и т.п. и они будут корректно интерпретированы и подобающе работоспособными?

Получается что-то наподобие "Кроссплатформенной ОС", оксюморон прям (:

Comment: Отличный вопрос !!!

Comment: Не кроссплатформенной ОС, а многоплатформенной ОС

Comment: теоретически все возможно, - даже вечный двигатель. реальность более сурова и недружелюбна к романтикам :)

по большому счету у всех известных мне ос есть программы которые обрабатывают файлы в зависимости от расширения. посему вполне вероятно создать ось, на  выполняемые файлы .exe повешать какой-то свой обработчик, для других аналогично, хотя ни один из этих форматов может быть не родным для данной оси.

Answer (score 2):

Существует же wine и разные его дериваты, которые худо-бедно позволяют на никсах запускать виндовские приложения. Что-то подобное есть и для маков. И на виндах есть способы запускать линуксовые приложения. Так что не только теоретически, но и практически уже нечто подобное существует, хотя и очень далекое от совершенства.

**ADDENDA:** deb - это не исполняемый файл, а установочный пакет Linux Debian и его производных (например, Ubuntu).

Comment: Думаю ТС немного не то имел ввиду: wine создает среду внутри среды, насколько я могу судить (она тупо создает папку windows в своей директории), автор же (ИМХО) интересуется, возможно ли создание оси, способной корректно работать с различными файловыми системами. Поправьте если неправ. как по мне, вопрос довольно интересен.

Comment: > исполняемыми файлами

из вопроса. Про файловые системы ни слова.

Под Windows есть [CoLinux](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colinux) и например [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) на его основе.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под термином "файловая система" ?

Comment: (Оффтопик) «Addenda» — множественное число, единственное будет «addendum.»

Add: Черт, на дату-то я не посмотрел. Некромансеры попутали.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно возможно. Но на пути будет множество сложностей и придётся проделать очень много лишней работы. Это было бы очень неэффективно с точки зрения ресурсов разработчиков. Создание действительно полноценной ОС требует довольно больших ресурсов и много времени, тестирования и т.п. Сделать две ОС в одной потребует ещё больше усилий и терпения.

Но теоретически всё это возможно. Ничто не мешает реализовать разные системные API одновременно, поддерживать несколько моделей организации файлов, разных абстракций, реализовать иксы и т.п. На уровне ядра придётся также реализовать сразу два вида API чтобы драйвера в ядре могли работать и не мешать друг другу. С другой стороны есть вероятность, что всё же будут ограничения на уровне ядра, связанные с разной архитектурой. Однако на прикладном уровне думаю это возможно, более чем. Такие вещи как wine доказывают, что это возможно. Только очень уж мучительно будет.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, да.

Т.е. подсистемы типа wine, cygwin, interix существуют, подкрутить загрузчик (+ подключение соответствующих разделяемых библиотек) тоже можно, хотя, на практике геморроя будет много.

Интереснее другое продолжение темы. Кроссплатформенный standalown модуль (естественно я имею в виду машинные коды и следовательно речь идет об одной и той же процессорной архитектуре).

Возможно к такой штуке нужен будет миниустановщик (меняющий magic и если потребуется формат файла для загрузчика ОС) в зависимости от ОС. Идея состоит в том, что функция в точке входа определяет (сама, на лету) текущее окружение и "подстраивается" к нему. Очевидно, что система разработки (компоновщик и библиотеки) должна "обладать знаниями" о возможных целевых ОС.

IMHO идея интересная, но дальше теоретических размышлений сам не двигался. На практике же широко используются интерпретаторы типа python, perl ...

Comment: Такое потребует поддержки со стороны ОС. И со стороны сгенерированного кода потребуется много танцев с бубном. Но это, конечно, возможно. Только зачем так сложно? Не проще ли обычные виртуальные машины использовать? (что все и делают).
<br />
PS: Несколько лет назад один товарищ с freepascal (или откуда-то отттуда) предлагал, чтобы ОС анализировала машинный код и подменяла вызовы функций внутри бинарника, чтобы он мог выполняться на некой системе Х.

Comment: Нее..., Вы идею не поняли. Она в том, **что ОС не трогаем**. Соответственно с VM тоже не заморачиваемся. 

В идеале воткнул флэшку, кликнул на файл, программка тебе "Привет !" сказала.

А танцев много (просто браться страшно).

Comment: А вы не сделаете такое. Если ОС не трогать, то винда не будет читать и даже пытаться запускать ELF. Если только сделать несколько загрузчиков, а общий бинарник тянуть отдельно.. но тогда получится куча исполняемых файлов. Никак по-другому я себе не представляю такое.

Comment: У меня под WinXP установлен andLinux. Если elf лежит в общей папке, то в этой папке можно запустить терминал линукс или файловый менеджер, а из них уже можно запустить elf и программка скажет "Привет!" :)

Смысла с нуля создавать ос, в которой будут запускаться и exe и elf, я не вижу, тем более что уже есть возможноть делать это под существующими ос.

Comment: Да, но это модификация для ОС, которую надо устанавливать специально заранее.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, говоря о "миниустановщике" я имел в виду именно разруливание ситуации с отказом запускать модуль. Потом, разве я где-нибудь упомянул ELF ?

Comment: @insolor, полностью согласен (просто Ваш комментарий не к тому ответу). Я **не говорил** о новой ОС.

Comment: Кстати говоря, винда не так проста и загрузчик процессов определяет к какой **подсистеме** обращаться.